# Mavericks Dock Lag

Tags: macos, mac, graphics-card, osx-mavericks, dock

Im having an weird bug on my MacBook Pro. When I start the machine, the dock have some graphic lag, the same when I open and close windows.

The solution is simple, just open the AutoCAD and close it and the bug is gone.

The same if I open AutoDesk Maya or other similar 3D program. My question where is not how to fix it, but why it happens.

Its like Mavericks on the start thinks: Well you can only use a little memory of the graphic card! But if i open AutoCad, its like: Oh you are opening AutoCad so its better starting boosting the graphic card and giving you more memory.

I bet there is something that is forcing Mavericks to think like this.

Any help is welcome! =)

Comment: Any image of what you're seeing would help a lot. Are you able to provide one?

Comment: Right now im not in home, but when i arrive i will try to upload a vídeo so you can see the ui lag that is making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into the same issue, but I don't think the graphics have anything to do with it.

Mavericks does the same thing Windows does in that it gets you to a desktop as quickly as possible on a fresh boot even though it's still loading services in the background.

When I fresh boot my Mac and log in, I fire up Activity Monitor first thing and I can see that disk I/O is still through the roof for about a minute afterwards.  During that time, the machine (including the dock) feels quite sluggish.  But once the activity dies down, the whole system becomes responsive and smooth again.  If I had an SSD (as all new Macs do) I am sure this wouldn't be as much of an issue.

Maya and AutoCAD are pretty beefy programs.  The time it takes them to launch probably gives the system enough time to fully initialize thus providing the impression that those programs are somehow kicking something over that's making things work properly.

Comment: Actually my macbook pro have 512 GB SSD, it should be fast on it, but never thought about the disk I/O activity. I restart a couple of times my macbook to see the lag again, with the monitor activity and the lag is gone, like never happens. You are probably right about this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the topic is old, but i solve the problem by doing some procedures.

If the problem insists, you may need to restore you Mac Os X to their factory settings.

**Warning**: By doing this you will automatacly clean all your files,documents, programs that is store in your HDD. I suggest before this use Time Machine or other backup program to save all your files.

Here is the link how to restore to factory settings:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

After the restoration, update to the last update, on this case is version 10.9.3.

If the problem insists or other problems that came with this procudure i suggest to call Apple support.

For Yosemite users this problem in general doesnt affect.

Hope this can help anyone.